# substitute all numbers in a matrix with equivalent letters

Tags: python, string, numbers

There is a huge matrix whose elements are numbers in the range of 1 to 15. I want to transform the matrix to the one whose elements be letters such that 1 becomes "a", 2 becomes "b", and so on. As a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np, numpy.random
numpy.random.seed(1)
A = pd.DataFrame (np.random.randint(1,16,10).reshape(2,5)) 
# A     0   1   2   3   4
#   0   6   12  13  9   10
#   1   12  6   1   1   2
```

The expected output is

```
# B     0   1   2   3   4
#   0   f   l   m   i   j
#   1   l   f   a   a   b
```

I can do it with a loop but for a huge matrix, it doesn't seem logical. There should be a more pythonic way to do it. In `R`, `chartr` is the function for such a replacement. For the numbers between 1 to 9, it works like this: `chartr("123456789", "ABCDEFGHI", A)`. What is the equivalent in Python?

Comment: just so you understand, `applymap` is just a thinly veiled loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chr`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> numpy.random.seed(1)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 16, 10).reshape(2, 5))
>>> df

    0   1   2  3   4
0   6  12  13  9  10
1  12   6   1  1   2


>>> df = df.applymap(lambda n: chr(n + 96))
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  f  l  m  i  j
1  l  f  a  a  b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. If possible, I would advise against use of `lambda` and `apply` via `pandas`, as these are loopy and have overheads.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

np.random.seed(1)
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,16,10).reshape(2,5)) 

#     0   1   2  3   4
# 0   6  12  13  9  10
# 1  12   6   1  1   2

d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1))
A_mapped = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(d.get)(A.values))

#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0  F  L  M  I  J
# 1  L  F  A  A  B
```